# Playing wave audio from JS array data in browser

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run wav form data as audio in browser via javascript?
Array looks like this:

```
wav: [
     0.5000883,  0.4670803, 0.54179835, 0.34557748,  0.5482587,  0.6353856,
     0.5275184, 0.41828325,  0.7173671, 0.47514692, 0.50390095, 0.49805835, ...]
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: https://rochars.github.io/wavefile/